# Node.JS - How to escape multiple nested callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request

I've currently got a expressJS app and I'm trying to retrieve information from an API using the `getStats` function. However, the `profile` route I've written seems to be multiple nested callbacks. How would I prevent this? Is there a way to make it get all of the stats, then assign them to variables after they all of the stats are retrieved?

```
function getStats(access_token, time_range, x, callback) {
    var stats = [];

    var options = {
        url: 'www.example.com',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    }

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            for (i = 0; i < body.items.length; i++) {
                stats.push(body.items[i].name);
            }
            return callback(stats);
        }
    })

}

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    var access_token = 1234;

    getStats(access_token, 's', 'x', function(a){
        console.log(a);

        getStats(access_token, 's', 'y', function(b){
            console.log(b);

            getStats(access_token, 'm', 'x', function(c){
                console.log(c);

                getStats(access_token, 'm', 'y', function(d){
                    console.log(d);

                    getStats(access_token, 'l', 'x', function(e){
                        console.log(e);

                        getStats(access_token, 'l', 'y', function(f){
                            console.log(f);

                            res.send(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n" + d + "\n" + e + "\n" + f);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest that you [look into Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Promises allow you to avoid the type of callback nesting like you've just shown. See my example which illustrates your example in Promise form:

```
function getStats(access_token, time_range, x, prevResult) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (prevResult) {
            resolve([...prevResult, "test", "test", "test"]);
        } 
        return resolve(["test", "test", "test"]);

    });
}

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    var access_token = 1234;

    getStats(access_token, 's', 'x')
        .then((a) => {
            console.log(a);
            return getStats(access_token, 's', 'y', a);
        })
        .then((b) => {
            console.log(b);
            return getStats(access_token, 'm', 'x', b);
        })
        .then((c) => {
            console.log(c);
            return getStats(access_token, 'm', 'y', c);
        })
        .then((d) => {
            console.log(d);
            return getStats(access_token, 'l', 'x', d);
        })
        .then((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            return getStats(access_token, 'l', 'y', e);
        })
        .then((f) => {
            console.log(f);
            res.send(f.join("\n"));
    });
});
```

As you can see the nested callback structure and replace with a much more readable format. Read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

The above could even be rewritten using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which looks even nicer:

```
function getStats(access_token, time_range, x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve(["test", "test", "test"]);
    });
}

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    var access_token = 1234;

    Promise.all([
        getStats(access_token, 's', 'x'),
        getStats(access_token, 's', 'y'),
        getStats(access_token, 'm', 'x'),
        getStats(access_token, 'm', 'y'),
        getStats(access_token, 'l', 'x'),
        getStats(access_token, 'l', 'y')
    ]).then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
        res.send(values.join("\n"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is the example using abstract getStats? It's very specific in the question. Btw, there's `request-promise`.

Comment: I have offered the easiest form of the problem at hand that I could come up with to illustrate how to go about improving his code structure. It's very easy to copy paste this and add a few console.log lines to see how it is working. Since the original post did not have API call I could easily reproduce (or even a working one), I've taken the liberty to simplify the code in order to illustrate my point. Also `request-promise` looks pretty nice so I guess that could be an additional option to prettify the code some more. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Promises will help with that, or moving your callbacks into their own function expressions outside of the route, and then calling it in the route once will help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that callback hell is that you are not using middlewares where the express app is supporting it.

Basically a way to write an express app is relying in the callbacks and so on. But the counterpart is that this will lead to as what you pointed out the callback hell.

This happens also with promises as well and it's called the promise hell when not properly handled.

The best way to avoid this two patterns are moving into the middlewares solutions.

```
function getAccesstoken(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.something) {
        return next('Error, something was not specified');
    }
    req.someRequestVariable = 'set_something';
    next();
}

function processRequest(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.someRequestVariable);
    res.send(200);
}

app.use(function genericHandlerForEveryCall() {
    console.log('This is being called in every request');
})

app.get('/profile', getAccesstoken, processRequest);
```